# Submit multiple data from dynamic form with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit, sqlsrv

I'm trying to submit multiple inputs generated with jQuery append() method in the same general form.  I'm new to jquery and AJAX.

this HTML form is a close exemple to mine.

```
<form id="dynamic_form" method="POST">
    <select name="account1" id="account1">
        <option>Choose option</option>
        <option>Option 1/option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
    </select><br>
    <select name="task1" id="task1">
        <option>Choose option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select><br>
    <textarea name="note1" id="note1" required="required"></textarea><br>

    <button type="button" id="addbtn">Add</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <input type="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

this is my jquery add form code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 1;
        $('#addbtn').click(function(){
            i++;
        $('#dynamic_form').append('<select name="account'+i+'" id="account'+i+'"><option>Choose option</option><option>Option 1/option><option>Option 2</option> //etc ...');
});
```

when clicking on add button i get new drop-down menus and input fields with incrementing IDs.

i don't know how i should use AJAX in my situation to send my data to "submission.php" and submit it to my **sql server** database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `serialize()` method to build a querystring of all content within the `form`. You can then provide this to the `data` property of the `$.ajax()` request to send the information to your PHP logic.

Also note that as you're using PHP you don't need to worry about creating incremental `name` and `id` attributes at runtime. Just suffix each field name with `[]` and PHP will interpret the values as an array. In turn this means that all the account `select` elements are identical, so you can simply `clone()` them instead. This makes the JS much more tidy and succinct.

Finally, your use of `append()` to the `form` places the new content after the buttons. You may want to consider selecting the last `account[]` element and using `insertAfter()` instead:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $form = $('#dynamic_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(data);

    /*
    $.ajax({
      url: 'yourpage.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: data,
      success: function() {
        console.log('It worked!');
      }
    });
    */
  });

  $('#addbtn').click(function() {
    let $last = $form.find('select[name="account[]"]:last');
    $last.clone().insertAfter($last);
  });
});
```

```css
select,
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="dynamic_form" method="POST">
  <select name="account[]">
    <option>Choose option</option>
    <option>Option 1/option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <select name="task[]">
    <option>Choose option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="note" required="required"></textarea>

  <button type="button" id="addbtn">Add</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  <input type="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I used the serialize() method but it doesn't show the data from the new generated forms in the console. it shows the data from the first form only.

Comment: Its almost as if the Jquery code doesn't recognize the new generated forms when running (clicking on the submit button).

Comment: In that case check to make sure your HTML is valid. Normally that's caused by invalid HTML which renders the controls outside of the `form` element, so they're not included in the submission